# Comparing a Downloaded String to a List in Python

Tags: python, comparison, analysis

I'm trying to create a sentiment analyser in Python that downloads text and analyses it against a list of negative and positive words. For every match within the text with a word in *poswords.txt* there should be a `+1` score and for every match within the text in *negwords.txt* there should be a `-1` score, the overall score for the text will be the sentiment score. This is how I have tried to do it but I keep just getting a score of 0.

The answer below does not seem to work, I keep getting a sentiment score of 0.

```
 split = text.split()
    poswords = open('poswords.txt','r')
    for word in split:
        if word in poswords:
            sentimentScore +=1
    poswords.close()

    negwords = open('negwords.txt','r')
    for word in split:
        if word in negwords:
            sentimentScore -=1
    negwords.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

`poswords` and `negwords` in your code are just file handles, you are not reading the words in those files.

Here:

```
split = text.split()
poswords = open('poswords.txt','r')
pos = []
for line in poswords:
    pos.append(line.strip())
for word in split:
    if word in pos:
        sentimentScore +=1
poswords.close()

negwords = open('negwords.txt','r')
neg = []
for line in negwords:
    neg.append(line.strip())
for word in split:
    if word in neg:
        sentimentScore -=1
negwords.close()
```

If the files are huge, the above is not a optimal solution. Create a dictionary for positive and negative words:

```
input_text = text.split() # avoid using split as a variable name, since it is a keyword
poswords = open('poswords.txt','r')
pos_dict = defaultdict(int)
for line in poswords:
    pos_dict[line.strip()] += 1
poswords.close()

negwords = open('negwords.txt','r')
neg_dict = defaultdict(int)
for line in negwords:
    neg_dict[line.strip()] += 1
negwords.close()

sentiment_score = 0
for word in input_text:
    if word in pos_dict:
        sentiment_score += 1
    elif word in neg_dict:
        sentiment_score -=1
```

Comment: Hi Warunsl, thanks for your quick reply, however, this code doesnt seem to work, I am still getting a sentiment score of 0 on all of the 'input_text' I am passing through the analyser